# Adding a value to each column sequentially

Tags: python

I am a novice programmer in python and was wondering if I can get a little help. The code I am about to show below prints out a simple array based on the users input for # of rows and # of columns. The array itself is filled with underscores ('_'):

```
new_list = []
undersc = '_'
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    new = []
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
        new.append(undersc)
    new_list.append(new)

for c in range(len(new_list[0])):
    print()
for r in range(len(new_list)):
    for c in range(len(new_list[0])):
        array = print((new_list[r][c]), end=" ")
    print()
return array
```

The console outputs the following:

```
_  _  _  _  _

_  _  _  _  _

_  _  _  _  _
```

The output that I need to get now is this:

```
Z _ _ _ _

Z Z _ _ _

Z Z Z _ _
```

Basically I see that each column is filling up sequential as you move down a row however, I am lost as to how I can get my code above to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rename `i` as `row_num`, `j` as `column_number`, and it becomes clear you need to append `'Z'` instead of `'_'` if and only if `row_number >= columns_number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
new.append(undersc)
```

to this:

```
new.append(undersc if j > i else 'Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Building up the list

```
>>> rows = 3
>>> columns = 5
>>> res = [['Z'] * pos + ['_'] * (columns - pos) for pos in range(1, rows + 1)]
>>> res
 [['Z', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
  ['Z', 'Z', '_', '_', '_'],
  ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', '_', '_']]

>>> for row in res:
        print(''.join(row))
Z _ _ _ _
Z Z _ _ _
Z Z Z _ _
```

### Using your list `new_list`

```
for pos, row in enumerate(new_list, 1):
    print(' '.join(['Z'] * pos), ' '.join(row[pos:]))
```

prints:

```
Z _ _ _ _
Z Z _ _ _
Z Z Z _ _
```